# DjangoRestFramework - How to filter ViewSet's object list based on end-users input?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my ViewSet:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-createdAt')
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsLikeOrOwnerDeleteOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, location=self.request.user.userextended.location)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
            """
            Extra context provided to the serializer class.
            """
            return {
                'request': self.request,
                'format': self.format_kwarg,
                'view': self,
                'location': self.request.user.userextended.location
            }

    @detail_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[IsFromLocationOrReadOnly])
    def like(self, request, pk=None):
        post = self.get_object()
        post.usersVoted.add(request.user)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

This is my router / `urls.py`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'posts', views.PostViewSet)
```

So when I go to `/posts` I get a list of all posts. What I want is to be able to allow the end-user to go to a specific URL like so: `/posts/username` and when he does, I want to give him all the posts of that specific username (the filtering will be simple. Something along these lines:

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(username=usernameProvidedByTheURL)
```

How do I go about doing this? Is it possible using DRF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your url:

```
url(r'^/post/(?P<username>\w+)/?$', PostViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
```

Then in your `PostViewSet`, overwrite the `get_queryset()` method to filter the data by `username`

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-createdAt')
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsLikeOrOwnerDeleteOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        return Post.objects.filter(username=username)
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to keep `/post/` endpoint to retrieve all post. Then you need to create  an extra view to handle `/post/username`

```
class PostsListByUsername(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

        def get_queryset(self):
            username = self.kwargs['username']
            return Post.objects.filter(username=username)
```

Then in your urls.py

```
url(r'^/post/(?P<username>\w+)/?$', PostsListByUsername.as_view()),
```

Note:
In your `get_serializer_context` method, you don't need to return `request`, `format` and `view`. DRF will append it for you.

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
        """
        Extra context provided to the serializer class.
        """
        return {
            'location': self.request.user.userextended.location
        }
```

Comment: But I also want to keep the functionality of getting all the posts by going to `/posts`. So if a user goes to `/posts` I want to return all posts. And then if a user goes to `/posts/1` I want to return the post who's `pk'` is 1. From your URL, if a user goes to `/post/username` (Note that it is without the letter 's'), and if we link that to PostViewSet's `list` and override `get_queryset()`, wouldn't the overridden `get_queryset()` also be called when I want to simply try to get a list of all post objects?

Comment: Is there a reason as to why the URL has a `?` at the end? It works good without the `?` for me but I'm just wondering if the `?` makes a difference or not.

Comment: `? `  is use to allow `/` (trailing slash) as optional character in your url. So,   your url rule will match with `/post/my_username/` or `/post/my_username`